# snmptrapd client configuration In Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, net-snmp, snmpd, snmptrapd

I successfully installed snmpd and cacti using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/installing-the-cacti-server-monitor-on-ubuntu-12-04-cloud-server
How to install Perl-Net-snmp module in Ubuntu?.because I want to receive traps in perl using NetSNMP::TrapReceiver.

Comment: To install from source, see the [install docs](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/INSTALL.html) for Net-SNMP. There's the `perl-Net-SNMP` package on Red Hat, but I don't see an equivalent for Debian, so you might have to build from source. Also, make sure you configured Net-SNMP with `--enable-embedded-perl`, or `NetSNMP::TrapReceiver` [won't work](https://metacpan.org/pod/NetSNMP::TrapReceiver#ABSTRACT).